# what is the difference between sockets and ports in a computer network?

Tags: sockets

I have trouble understanding this,
for example:-

1. I have tried connecting to google server(via http process) and also tried connecting to Youtube(again http process), will different sockets be created for each connection?
2. if i have different sockets, will port numbers be different since a socket is a combination of IP and
   port and IP here is fixed(my computer)?

Comment: For 2, are you referring to the source port or destination port? The source port on your computer that you're sending from will be a random port in the ephemeral port range, whereas the destination port it will be a set port decided by the server/service being used (`443` for HTTPS).

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. Duplicate.